# Firebase CI deploy as service account

Tags: firebase, firebase-cli

I have a CI pipeline to deploy my firebase changes to different environments. (dev, test, prod)

Currently, it works by running `firebase deploy --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN` command.

I have generated `$FIREBASE_TOKEN` by running `firebase login:ci` from my admin account which has access to all projects (dev, test, prod).

Now if someone gets access to dev CI he/she can deploy directly to `production` reusing the same `$FIREBASE_TOKEN` token.

How can I authenticate per firebase project to generate 3 separate tokens for each environment?